# how to filter on property of type List<string,string> using odata

Tags: c#, odata

i have an odata endpoint something like this.

[image]

object is like this

```
public class Propertey
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
public class MonitoringEvent : DocumentEntity
{
    public string AppName { get; set; }
    public string Service { get; set; }
    public string Fuction { get; set; }
    public string CorrelationId { get; set; }
    public List<Propertey> Properties { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

i want to be able to return all the items that has properties with key = "abc"

i was using something like

> localhost:7071/monitoringEvents?$filter=properties/key eq 'abc'

but it doesn't work.
is there a solution to it or

what if i change properties to type IDictionary ? what should be the query url like ?

**Update**
also tried

> localhost:7071/monitoringEvents?$filter=properties(key) eq 'abc'
> and
> localhost:7071/monitoringEvents?$expand=properties($filter=key eq 'abc')

didn't worked either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`any` can meet your requirement.

Checkout the following example:

```
~/monitoringEvents?$filter=Properties/any(p:p/Key eq 'abc')
```